# Single workflow starting multiple workflows

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2010, workflow-foundation

Good day,

I have a list that has a custom workflow that starts when an idem is created. I the workflow i have a codeActivity that creates multiple items on the list. This in turn starts multiple workflows.

I am having an issue that when one of the children workflows fails to start, the parent items workflows status changes from "in progress" to "error occurred". It seems that they are being started under the same thread. How do i start the children workflows so that they run independently? Is there a way to make them run in their own thread?

Here is the code im currently using to add new items:

```
bool first = true;
Foreach (file in files)
{
    if(first)
    {
        workflowProperties.Item["Title"] = file;
        workflowProperties.Item.Update();
        first = false;
    }
    else
    {
        var newItem = list.Items.Add();
        newItem["Title"] = file;
        newItem.Update();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and see what happens

```
bool first = true;
var file = string.Empty 
Foreach (file in files)
{
    var newItem = list.Items.Add();
    newItem["Title"] = file;
    newItem.Update();
    if(first)
    {    file=  file.name;             
        first = false;
    }    
}
workflowProperties.Item["Title"] = file;
    workflowProperties.Item.Update();
```

Comment: All the items add correctly. The issue is that if any of the items added fails to start, the parent item workflow fails and status gets to "error occurred"

Answer (score 0):

Try below code if you don't want to intiate workflow for other items

```
bool first = true;
Foreach (file in files)
{
    if(first)
    {
        workflowProperties.Item["Title"] = file;
        workflowProperties.Item.Update();
        first = false;
    }
    else
    {
        var newItem = list.Items.Add();
        newItem["Title"] = file;
    EventFiring eventFiring = new EventFiring();
    eventFiring.DisableHandleEventFiring();
        newItem.Update();
    eventFiring.EnableHandleEventFiring();
    }

}
```

Comment: I would like to start the workflow. I just dont want any child workflows to affect the main items workflow